# Is there a way I can keep something at a constant speed in C++ game?

Tags: c++, c++11, clock

I currently have a game where there is a player, enemies, and projectiles. The user can spawn projectiles to damage enemies. However, the problem that I am having, is that the enemies speed up the more projectiles the user spawns in a row. I tried to use a game clock to keep everything constant and my game loop is below.

```
while (window.isOpen())
{
    std::chrono::high_resolution_clock::time_point begin = std::chrono::high_resolution_clock::now();
    for (int i = 0; i < enemies.size(); i++)
    {
        enemies[i].move(begin, HEIGHT, WIDTH, player);
    }
    for (size_t i = 0; i < player.projectiles.size();)
    {
        if (player.projectiles[i].move(begin, WIDTH))
        {
            player.projectiles.erase(player.projectiles.begin() + i);
        }
        else
        {
            i++;
        }
    }
    for (int i = 0; i < enemies.size();)
    {
        for (int j = 0; j < player.projectiles.size();)
        {
            if (enemies[i].hit(player.projectiles[j]))
            {
                player.projectiles.erase(player.projectiles.begin() + j);
            }
            else
            {
                j++;
            }
        }
        if (enemies[i].hp <= 0)
        {
            enemies.erase(enemies.begin() + i);
        }
        else
        {
            i++;
        }
    }
    sf::Event event;
    while (window.pollEvent(event))
    {
        if (event.type == sf::Event::Closed)
        {
            window.close();
            break;
        }
        if (sf::Mouse::isButtonPressed(sf::Mouse::Right))
        {
            enemies.push_back(Enemy(100.0, 1.0, Mouse::getPosition().x, Mouse::getPosition().y, Color::White));
        }
        if (event.type == Event::KeyPressed)
        {
            if (event.key.code == player.up)
            {
                player.moving_up = true;
            }
            else if (event.key.code == player.down)
            {
                player.moving_down = true;
            }
            else if (event.key.code == player.right)
            {
                player.moving_right = true;
            }
            else if (event.key.code == player.left)
            {
                player.moving_left = true;
            }
            else if (event.key.code == player.shoot)
            {
                player.shooting = true;
            }
            if (event.key.code == player.exit)
            {
                window.close();
            }
        }
        if (event.type == Event::KeyReleased)
        {
            if (event.key.code == player.up)
            {
                player.moving_up = false;
            }
            else if (event.key.code == player.down)
            {
                player.moving_down = false;
            }
            else if (event.key.code == player.right)
            {
                player.moving_right = false;
            }
            else if (event.key.code == player.left)
            {
                player.moving_left = false;
            }
            else if (event.key.code == player.shoot)
            {
                player.shooting = false;
            }
        }
        player.input(begin, HEIGHT, WIDTH);
        for (int i = 0; i < enemies.size();)
        {
            for (int j = 0; j < player.projectiles.size();)
            {
                if (enemies[i].hit(player.projectiles[j]))
                {
                    player.projectiles.erase(player.projectiles.begin() + j);
                }
                else
                {
                    j++;
                }
            }
            if (enemies[i].hp <= 0)
            {
                enemies.erase(enemies.begin() + i);
            }
            else
            {
                i++;
            }
        }
    }
    window.clear();
    player.draw(window);
    for (int i = 0; i < enemies.size(); i++)
    {
        enemies[i].draw(window);
    }
    window.display();
}
```

The enemy.move function looks like this, where speed is set to 1.0:

```
void Enemy::move(std::chrono::high_resolution_clock::time_point begin, float height, float width, Player player)
{
    std::chrono::high_resolution_clock::time_point end = std::chrono::high_resolution_clock::now();
    if (player.x < this->x)
    {
        if (this->x - (enemy_speed * (std::chrono::duration_cast<std::chrono::microseconds>(end - begin).count()) / 1000.0) < 0)
        {
            this->x = 0;
        }
        else
        {
            this->x = this->x - (enemy_speed * (std::chrono::duration_cast<std::chrono::microseconds>(end - begin).count()) / 1000.0);
        }
        if (player.y < this->y)
        {
            if (this->y - (enemy_speed * (std::chrono::duration_cast<std::chrono::microseconds>(end - begin).count()) / 1000.0) < 0)
            {
                this->y = 0;
            }
            else
            {
                this->y = this->y - (enemy_speed * (std::chrono::duration_cast<std::chrono::microseconds>(end - begin).count()) / 1000.0);
            }
        }
        else
        {
            if (this->y + (enemy_speed * (std::chrono::duration_cast<std::chrono::microseconds>(end - begin).count()) / 1000.0) > (height - double(this->sprite.getSize().y)))
            {
                this->y = height - double(this->sprite.getSize().y);
            }
            else
            {
                this->y = this->y + (enemy_speed * (std::chrono::duration_cast<std::chrono::microseconds>(end - begin).count()) / 1000.0);
            }
        }
    }
    else
    {
        if (this->x + (enemy_speed * (std::chrono::duration_cast<std::chrono::microseconds>(end - begin).count()) / 1000.0) > (width - double(this->sprite.getSize().x)))
        {
            this->x = width - double(this->sprite.getSize().x);
        }
        else
        {
            this->x = this->x + (enemy_speed * (std::chrono::duration_cast<std::chrono::microseconds>(end - begin).count()) / 1000.0);
        }
        if (player.y < this->y)
        {
            if (this->y - (enemy_speed * (std::chrono::duration_cast<std::chrono::microseconds>(end - begin).count()) / 1000.0) < 0)
            {
                this->y = 0;
            }
            else
            {
                this->y = this->y - (enemy_speed * (std::chrono::duration_cast<std::chrono::microseconds>(end - begin).count()) / 1000.0);
            }
        }
        else
        {
            if (this->y + (enemy_speed * (std::chrono::duration_cast<std::chrono::microseconds>(end - begin).count()) / 1000.0) > (height - double(this->sprite.getSize().y)))
            {
                this->y = height - double(this->sprite.getSize().y);
            }
            else
            {
                this->y = this->y + (enemy_speed * (std::chrono::duration_cast<std::chrono::microseconds>(end - begin).count()) / 1000.0);
            }
        }
    }
    this->sprite.setPosition(this->x, this->y);
}
```

I apologize for the long segments of code but these are the relative parts and I don't know specifically what pieces of code you may need. Any help is greatly appreciated.

Comment: One "rule" I have made myself is that the *only* time you check a clock directly is the event loop. Callbacks should always use the value the event loop cached.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Bascially, to move something at a constant rate, you want to base the distance moved based on the elapsed time *since you previously moved that object*, not the elapsed time since the beginning of the current cycle, like you are doing here.

So your move function should be something like:

```
void Enemy::move(float height, float width, Player player) {
    std::chrono::high_resolution_clock::time_point now = std::chrono::high_resolution_clock::now();
    // various code that moves by enemy_speed * (now - prev_time)
    prev_time = now;
}
```

where `prev_time` is a field in the enemy object where you store the previous timestamp of movement.  You need to make sure you initialize it to an inital time properly, or the first move will "jump" unexpectedly.

You can reduce the number of times you query the clock by having a single timestamp for all the enemies/objects and passing in the elapsed time since the previous timestamp to all the move routines.

Comment: So should I start counting at the end of enemy.move?

Comment: @Kookies No, get the time prior to the loop and at the start of the loop get the time once more, calculate the difference to the previous time & replace the old time with the new one. Then update all entities in your game passing the difference you calculated... `auto lastTime = std::chrono::high_resolution_clock::now(); while (window.isOpen()) { auto now = std::chrono::high_resolution_clock::now(); auto const dt = now - lastTime; lastTime = now; ... enemies[i].move(dt, HEIGHT, WIDTH, player); ... }` (needs rewrite of `move()` of course)